# Pipe email template to netcat

Tags: file, email, pipe, netcat

I want to make an email file template to send it through netcat. This is the file I made:

```
HELO me
MAIL FROM: from@hotmail.com
RCPT TO: realMailAddress@hotmail.com
DATA
Subject: Example (Testing)
From: "Me" <itsme@email.com>
To: "You" <you@email.com>
It's really me...
.
```

Then I use `cat mailTemplate | nc mx1.hotmail.com 25` to send the email using Hotmail's SMTP server. Everything seems to work but netcat never reaches the end of DATA. This is what I got returned:

```
220 SNT004-MC1F10.hotmail.com Sending unsolicited commercial or bulk e-mail to Microsoft's computer network is prohibited. Other restrictions are found at http://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/anti-spam.mspx. Mon, 1 May 2017 14:51:27 -0700 
250 SNT004-MC1F10.hotmail.com (3.22.0.32) Hello [190.111.200.35]
250 from@hotmail.com....Sender OK
250 realMailAddress@hotmail.com 
354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>
```

And then connection closes, before reaching the ending < CRLF >.< CRLF > (Note: I double checked with an Hex editor if I have < CRLF >.< CRLF >)

If I write every line without piping the file the mail is sent correctly. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I already solved it. I don't really know where the issue was, but I used another file and it worked.